# How to trigger the wp_enqueue_scripts() without using get_header()?

Tags: wordpress

I have this page template that doesn't use the `header.php`. My goal is to be able to enqueue scripts without calling `get_header()`.

Is there a way to trigger the `wp_enqueue_scripts()` without using `get_header()`?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've never used it, however at like 781 of `wp-includes/script-loader.php` is a function, `wp_print_head_scripts()`.

It looks like if you call this directly, you will get all the scripts that are enqueued for the header. Check out the rest of the script, you'll find other wp_print_* methods.

HTH,

=C=